# Please unlock disk mmcblk0p3_crypt on hp laptop

Tags: boot, password-recovery

I keep getting this when I turn on my laptop. I am assuming this is requiring a password which I do not remember. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like you have a LUKS encrypted hard drive. If you don't know the password and it is a proper password, there is nothing you can do about it (apart from formating/reinstalling). If it is your laptop and you set it up, it is quite hard to understand why you don't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encrypt your disk while installing?
If so, You have to reinstall because there is no way to access recovery menu in case password is forgotton.
You might have done this:

```
Encrypt disk? [ yes ] 
Enter Password: ************
```

If that is the case, the text should have told you that without the password, you cannot unlock the disk and if you forgot the password, you have to reinstall operating system.

NOTE: I am new to the askubuntu community, so I currently do not know much about encrypted disks.

But, you cannot recover your disk if the password is forgotten.
However, reinstalling is a good option.

### Reinstalling Linux

First, take a USB.

Then, burn a Linux ISO to the USB disk.

Boot the laptop via the USB.

Then, reinstall Linux as you normally would.